# Mock certain part of the method using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm new to Moq and I would like to mock certain part of my method to test the business logic but having problem to mock the GetCountry method. Below is the code that I used as sample.

```
public class Class1
    {
        public void Process()
        {

            MyClass foo = new MyClass();
            var o = foo.GetCountry(); //I would like to mock this part.

            //Business Logic here
        }

    }

public class  MyClass : IFoo
{

    public List<string> GetCountry()
    {
        //Get the data from Database.. someone will do this
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Below is my Test Code that I used.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
            var mock = new Moq.Mock<IFoo>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.GetCountry()).Returns(new List<string> { "America", "Philippines", "Japan" });
            ClassLibrary1.Class1 foo = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
//still called the not implemented exception
            foo.Process();

}
```

Comment: @dotnetom's answer is perfectly correct. You should read about Dependency Injection. You will learn a lot about this kind of design

Comment: Thanks, I thought If I used IFoo foo = new MyClass(); I already implementing Dependency Injection here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code currently doesn't have an easy way to replace one implementation to another. Try this approach:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Instead of using a concrete class, use an interface
    // also, promote it to field
    IFoo _foo;

    // Create a constructor that accepts the interface
    public Class1(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    // alternatively use constructor which provides a default implementation
    public Class1() : this(new MyClass())
    {
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // Don't initialize foo variable here
        var o = _foo.GetCountry();
        //Business Logic here
    }
}
```

If you have such setup it is quite easy to mock it using your code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var mock = new Moq.Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.GetCountry()).Returns(new List<string> { "America", "Philippines", "Japan" });
    // Pass mocked object to your constructor:
    ClassLibrary1.Class1 foo = new ClassLibrary1.Class1(mock.Object);
    foo.Process();
}
```